# Load range to array depending on row numbers specified in sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, range, excel-indirect

Does anyone know how I can substitute the following code with a dynamic one that is linked to specific cells?

i.e. replace this

```
dim array1()
array1=range("a150:k250")
```

with something similar to that

```
dim array1()
array1=range(application.indirect("a"&c1&":k"&d1)
```

where c1 contains the value 150 and d1 the value 250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the indirect, use the Value property on C1 and D1 instead:

`array1=Range("a" & Range("c1").Value & ":k" & Range("d1").Value)`